Why would two neighboring kingdoms fight over an island?
This story is set in a medieval-esque world, on a continent roughly the size of Australia that is separated into six different kingdoms/territories. Each territory is its own sovereign country and has its own monarchy, however all kingdoms follow the same religion and have roughly the same laws. Each kingdom has its own magical creature as its 'mascot', and the kingdoms are not allowed to trade products or produce from another kingdom's creature, only its own.
There are two kingdoms that share a border, (the dragon and manticore kingdoms), and there is an island sort of in between them that overlaps into the other's territory. The island is large enough to have its own castle or keep and town, but it's still relatively small in the grand scheme of things. The island is located off the coast of both territories.
My question is, what would cause these two kingdoms to fight over this island? At the end of the day it's not super important due to its size. If there are any real-life examples of something like this happening I could take inspiration, I'd also love to know (as long as that doesn't technically make this two questions).

Heligoland in the North Sea. Just about any island in the Adriatic and the Aegean seas, for example Rhodes or Corfu. Etc. Islands in the sea are like castles on land... Have you even looked at the history of the islands around Europe?

@AlexP I haven't but I definitely will, thank you!

Is the island in the middle of a lake that divides their territory, or off the coastline of both kingdoms or what?  What exploitable resources are on the island or in the water around it?  We can't answer this, but the answers from your world will pretty much give you your answer.

Rome and Carthage mostly fought First (and partly Second) Punic War for the control of Sicily. Maybe it's somewhat more than a castle and a keep, but still nothing eyebrow-raising in the Mediterranean.

Perhaps see Faulkland Islands War between Britain and Argentina? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falklands_War

Questions about the motivation of characters or organizations are not suitable for this site.

Besides, this is waaaay too broad a question.

Please do basic research. So many islands have been locations of war/conquest/conflict.  Almost any island in and around Europe. Guano islands, WW2  Pacific. China and 9 dash line. etc.

fighting over islands os so common in history you really don't need ot justify it.

The Liancourt Rocks have been argued over for ages by Japan and South Korea, despite being literal rocks with nearly zero usable surface area.

There are three reasons: Location, Location, Location

More seriously: Location with respect to trade routes, location with respect to resources, location with respect to important landmarks. Note that many of the answers include one or more of these reasons

VTC:Too Story-Based. The [help/on-topic] specifically prohibits questions about character or organizational choices.

Also, Stack Exchange is a last resort, not a first. You can search the site to find stuff, but actually asking your own question should be done after you have exhausted your research skills. And if you find what you are looking for elsewhere, but then decide that the question still needs to be asked here, you can answer your own question - "Share your knowledge, Q&A-style!", as the 'Ask Question' form freely advertises

VTO: This question is about how to make the setting fit with the plot, not the plot itself.  The plot (that the kingdoms will go to war over the island) has already been defined by the OP.  The WorldBuilding problem here is that Geography and Politics of the region he's designed does not seem to make the island important enough to be worth fighting over; so, he needs to modify or justify his setting for his plot to make sense.

Control of Trade Routes
If this island is near the entrance to a large body of water, then it could control trade access to an entire region.  Most kingdoms throughout history have drawn thier borders across major geographic features like these; so, it is reasonable to assume that if this island is off the coast of two kingdoms, that it will also be at the mouth of a major river or sea. Given the right geography, this island could form 2 narrow straits between the sea and open trade with the other 4 kingdoms.
If the island is split, then both kingdoms have full control over 1 straight and have full access to trade, but if one kingdom could fully control the island, then they could erect fortifications to prevent ships from the other kingdom from passing through either straight.  If they did this, then the kingdom with the island could impose tariffs, embargos, and blocades on all trade goods going in or out of the sea.
This would be especially advantageous if dragons and manticores can only be breed somewhere deep inland, because this could prevent the kingdom from being able to economically export thier most valuable products.  In the medieval period, a lot of places still did not have road access; so, switching to exporting via wagons could be anywhere from way more expensive to not an option at all.
Military Strategic Value
Sailing an army across any wide part of the sea would require a lot of ships, and supplying an army across the sea would mean that if your navy gets sunk, then your army gets cut off from supplies, reinforcements, and means of retreat.
However, being at the narrow entrance to a sea, he who owns the island could build bridges, or need far fewer and simpler ships to resupply the army because they are crossing at the narrowest point.


+1 for Dragons and Manticores - the most critical factor in Naval supremacy and strategy.

Fishing Rights and Navy Bases
Traditionally, islands and the waters around them are prime locations for fishing fleets.  Dragons and Manticores both being apex predators, if you can convince them to eat seafood you can feed them MUCH more economically than relying on livestock.  The kingdom that controls the island also controls the waters around it for fishing, and there's your conflict.
Secondly, if it's big enough to have a castle or small town (and especially if it also has a fishing fleet) it's big enough to have some sort of strategic naval purpose.  Assuming a decent harbor your island could be critical to maritime security, as it gives fleets a place to weather storms and resupply/repair.  In a medieval setting a LOT of a nation's naval power comes from civilian mariners, both in the form of sailors and ships. Basically all naval transport was civilian, and civilian transport vessels could be refitted as warships (it happened quite a lot on the English side of the 100 years war at least) which means your merchant marine, such as it was, can have huge implications for national security.

As an inherently inconsequential piece of land, conflict over it could be symbolic - neighboring states can settle their differences by staging combat confined to the island, sparing their citizens and lands from the ravages of real full-scale war.
Since your setting appears to be fantasy, it could be the location of an entrance to an underworld, expansive cavern, submerged temple, etc. In other words, the value of the island is in its access to what lies beneath it, which could simply be more arable land far larger than the island itself, or a place rich with coveted resources, or a massive network of caves providing hidden access to other parts of the continent, etc.
Since both kingdoms subscribe to the same religious system, the island can be significant in their beliefs or their particular interpretations of religious texts. They might then disagree on how the island should be tended, or believe controlling the island elevates their standing in the religious community and the eyes of the people. Or a prophesy motivates control of the island by claiming its owners will see some kind of prosperity, or that not controlling the island will bring disaster and ruin. Similarly, it could have areligious historical value, or even just sentimental value to the leaders of both nations.
It could be coveted as a gift - in a society where land is a customary gift or reward among nobility, a lovely island with little strategic value would be better to give away than an inland area that contributes to your nation's food supply or hosts your trade traffic. This could be especially preferable if these nations are part of a larger coalition or empire led by a higher authority demanding compulsory gifts of land - either to minimize the blow to their own economies, or to afford a more impressive gift to their overlords and ingratiate them.

Especially given that all the kingdoms share a religion, the island could have some importance within the mythology of that religion, so protecting it and maintaining control over it could be considered valuable for symbolic reasons. A potential real-life example might be the Temple Mount in Jerusalem.
Also lots of countries have territorial disputes over islands. A couple examples I can think of are: Machias Seal Island (US and Canada; has led to disputes over lobster fishing) and Hans Island (Canada and Denmark; check out the Whisky War).
Sometimes countries will dispute who owns an island based on differing interpretations of some old treaty. Say for example the border was drawn dependent on the location of a river, but the river's location changed since the treaty was written.
Another interesting example is the Principality of Sealand.


The island is the seat of a formerly independent principality, now split between the two rival kingdoms. Holding this seat adds legitimacy to claims on the lands of this principality.
The island provides an useful anchorage considering the prevailing winds and currents. Medieval ships are bad at tacking into the wind. And the castle secures/defends the best (or only) fresh water source on the island.
Due to the shape of the island and the coastline, the island has the most convenient salt pans for the region.


Expert shipbuilders
Much like the Netherlands during the European colonial era, your island could be well-known for its expert shipbuilders. This could lead you to model other things off enlightenment-era Netherlands, like their invention of modern-day capitalism and market exchanges, possibly with some powerful stock or commodities exchange being centered in that castle of yours. And much like Netherlands in real life, this would make for a tempting piece of land to control.
